# Bootstrap Dropdowns and Popovers call parent element's hide function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When a Bootstrap Dropdown item is selected or a Popover closed, the popped up content is closed. However, a call is also made to the hide() function of the parent:

```
<div id="Dropdown" class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="Button" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" data-placement=bottom title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>

<script>
Button.hide = function() {console.log('hide button called')};
Dropdown.hide = function() {console.log('hide dropdown called')};
</script>
```

In the above code, messages will appear on the console when the dropdown or popover are dismissed. Looking at the stack trace, the actual call to the hide function is coming from jQuery.

This happens in both Bootstrap 3 and 4.

Is there anyway to prevent this from happening? If not, is there a way to detect if hide() is being called from jQuery?

Comment: try build snippet /fiddle so we can try

Comment: Here's the fiddle! https://jsfiddle.net/ghenne/yeo3nh17/

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how will we stop the event but it's dispatched from Bootstrap. I have used unminified version and below is a snippet from Bootstrap 4 which generates `hide` event as shown in call stack by chrome. jQuery fires click on window event which Bootstrap listens and afterwards fires `hide` event for every element which should be hidden.

```
Dropdown._clearMenus = function _clearMenus(event) {
  if (event && event.which === RIGHT_MOUSE_BUTTON_WHICH) {
    return;
  }

  var backdrop = $(Selector.BACKDROP)[0];
  if (backdrop) {
    backdrop.parentNode.removeChild(backdrop);
  }

  var toggles = $.makeArray($(Selector.DATA_TOGGLE));

  for (var i = 0; i < toggles.length; i++) {
    var parent = Dropdown._getParentFromElement(toggles[i]);
    var relatedTarget = { relatedTarget: toggles[i] };

    if (!$(parent).hasClass(ClassName.OPEN)) {
      continue;
    }

    if (event && event.type === 'click' && /input|textarea/i.test(event.target.tagName) && $.contains(parent, event.target)) {
      continue;
    }

    var hideEvent = $.Event(Event.HIDE, relatedTarget);
    $(parent).trigger(hideEvent);
    if (hideEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) {
      continue;
    }

    toggles[i].setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');

    $(parent).removeClass(ClassName.OPEN).trigger($.Event(Event.HIDDEN, relatedTarget));
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to detect the popup showing in the show.bs.popover event. Only do the hide if no popup was involved. Here's the code for Button in the sample above:

```
$('#Button').on('show.bs.popover', function () {
  Button.popoverShowing = true;
})

Button.hide = function() {
  if (Button.popoverShowing) {
    Button.popoverShowing = false;
    return;
  }
  Button.style.display = "none";
};
```